ISO_C_BINDING, calling C from Fortran
I have a C code (I am not the owner of said code) that generates the following structures
struct Vector
{
  int size;
  double data[3];
};

struct VerticesVect
{
  int size;
  struct Vector* data;
};

And so on : there are a lot of additional constructs (typically structures of the previously defined structure).
I need to call said C code/library from a Fortran code. The Fortran code will use the previously C-generated structures. The Fortran code won't write / edit them in any way, it just needs them as input.
I am trying to figure out a way to declare these types in Fortran so that I can use them.
use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING

followed by
type, bind(c) :: Vector
          integer(kind=C_INT32_T) :: size
          real(kind=C_DOUBLE) :: data(3)
      end type Vector

is obviously fine.
  type, bind(c) :: VerticesVect
      integer(kind=c_int) :: size
      type(Vector), dimension(:) :: data
  end type VerticesVect

is not valid though ("data must have an explicit shape"), nor
  type, bind(c) :: VerticesVect
      integer(kind=c_int) :: size
      type(Vector), pointer :: data
  end type VerticesVect

("Component 'data' cannot have the POINTER attribute because it is a member of the BIND(C) derived type 'verticesvect'")
nor seems to be valid any combination of allocatable, pointer, positioning of (:) that I could think of.
Unfotunately, specifying a static size such that it is big enough to cover all cases is not an acceptable solution, as the "compounded" maximum sizes of all subsequent constructions end up leading to an unreasonably large total object.
Is there a way to write these declarations such that the compiler accepts it and everything maps correctly ? Can/should i use the c_ptr type ? Can/should I get rid of the bind(c) ?
Thanks for your help

You also need to know how the C compiler is aligning different sized fields in the struct.

"Can/should i use the c_ptr type ?", yes. struct Vector* data is a pointer, so can you explain what gives you uncertainty?

@francescalus I have never written a line of code in C and never had to interface with C. That makes me quite uncertain :)

Not exactly, @stark.  bind(c) in the Fortran declaration of type VerticesVect instructs that the type should be laid out the same as a corresponding C structure type.  The whole point of C binding features of modern Fortran is that the programmer does not need to know C implementation details.

Your two C types seem similar in structure, each with a size and associated storage for items, but they differ in that struct Vector has a (fixed-size) array for storing items in the structure itself, whereas struct VerticesVect has a pointer to separate item storage.  There's nothing inherently wrong with that, but it makes me a little suspicious.  Since you're still having trouble, I ask whether you're sure that those structure definitions are what you are actually working with?

This ...
      type(Vector), dimension(:) :: data

... attempts to declare member data as an assumed-shape array.  This is wrong in the C sense that C pointers are not arrays.  It is also wrong in the C-binding sense that interoperable defined types are explicitly forbidden from having members that are assumed-size or assumed-shape arrays.
This ...
      type(Vector), pointer :: data

... seems more logical, but it is also incorrect because Fortran pointers and C pointers, though similar in concept, are not wholly analogous.  The C-binding maps C pointers to type type(c_ptr).  There are some caveats wrapped around that, but we don't need to dig into those here.
Thus, the way to define an interoperable user-defined type corresponding to a C structure with a pointer member is to use type(c_ptr) for the corresponding member on the Fortran side and to give the type the bind(c) attribute:
  type, bind(c) :: VerticesVect
      integer(kind=c_int) :: size
      type(c_ptr) :: data
  end type VerticesVect

Additionally, you will want to be able to access the Vector objects from the Fortran side.  For that, you will probably want to engage ISO_C_BINDING's c_f_pointer() function.  This is the main interoperable bridge between C pointers and Fortran pointers. For example:
    type(VerticesVect) :: vertices

    ! ... assign an appropriate value to 'vertices' ...

    type(Vector), dimension(:), pointer :: vectors
    call c_f_pointer(vertices%data, vectors, (/vertices%size/))

    ! ... use 'vectors' to access the data ...

Although you say you need only read access, both read and write access should work fine.

Addendum: complete example
The following demo compiles successfully and works as expected for me:
main.f90
program vectors
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding

    implicit none

    type, bind(c) :: Vector
        integer(kind=c_int) :: size
        real(kind=c_double) :: data(3)
    end type Vector

    type, bind(c) :: VerticesVect
        integer(kind=c_int) :: size
        type(c_ptr) :: data
    end type VerticesVect

    interface
        function generate3DVertices() bind(C, name='generate3DVertices')
            use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
            type(c_ptr) :: generate3DVertices
        end function generate3DVertices
    end interface

    type(VerticesVect), pointer :: vertices
    type(c_ptr) verticesPtr

    verticesPtr = generate3DVertices()
    call c_f_pointer(verticesPtr, vertices)
    call write_vectors(vertices)

contains

    subroutine write_vectors(vertices)
        type(VerticesVect), intent(in) :: vertices
        type(Vector), dimension(:), pointer :: vectors
        integer :: i

        call c_f_pointer(vertices%data, vectors, (/vertices%size/))
        write(6, *) 'Fortran vectors:'
        do i = 1, vertices%size
            write(6, '(3f10.6)') vectors(i)%data
        end do
    end subroutine write_vectors

end program

vect.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_VERTICES 3

struct Vector {
  int size;
  double data[3];
};

struct VerticesVect {
  int size;
  struct Vector* data;
};

struct VerticesVect *generate3DVertices(void) {
    struct VerticesVect *vertices = malloc(sizeof *vertices);

    if (!vertices) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    vertices->size = NUM_VERTICES;
    vertices->data = calloc(NUM_VERTICES, sizeof *vertices->data);
    if (!vertices->data) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    puts(" C vectors:");
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            vertices->data[i].data[j] = rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
        }
        printf("%10.6f%10.6f%10.6f\n",
               vertices->data[i].data[0], vertices->data[i].data[1], vertices->data[i].data[2]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    fflush(stdout);

    return vertices;
}

Makefile
OBJ = main.o vect.o

FC = gfortran

all: demo

demo: $(OBJ)
    $(FC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

The program calls calls a C function to generate random vectors and print C's interpretation of them, then prints the Fortran interpretation of the same.  When I run it, the vectors printed by C are identical to the ones printed by Fortran (to the 6-digit precision used on both sides).

All derived types are explicitly forbidden from having assumed-size and assumed-shape array components.

I don't have
a copy of the spec at hand, @francescalus, but the secondary docs I checked (i) contained the explicit prohibition I mentioned, and (ii) limited the scope of the more general prohibition you describe to members that do not have the pointer or allocatable attribute.  I didn't think it useful to go into full detail in this answer.

Any array with the pointer or allocatable attribute is by definition not an assumed-size or assumed-shape array. It's a genuine restriction that while a non-interoperable derived type may have a deferred-shape array component, an interoperable one may not. But there's no deferred-shape array in the question. Seeing as components can never be assumed-shape or assumed-size arrays (because only dummy arguments can be), saying it's "wrong in the C-binding sense" seems an odd statement.

For example, saying "interoperable derived types are forbidden from being called doubleprecision" is true, but not terribly helpful.

@JohnBollinger How do I then access the values in the vector pointer ? I have tried giving a target to this pointer, but my efforts have failed. type(Vector), dimension(:), target :: vectors_content leads to the error cannot have deferred shape.

@ParkerLewis, this answer already provides an example (to which I just applied a minor correction), and it works for me.  Note that your type(Vector), dimension(:), target is not the same as my type(Vector), dimension(:), pointer.  The pointer attribute must be present.

Yes, I defined vectors as you did, but then I'm running into trouble. The content of vectors is garbage.  I wonder if it's not related to vertices%size, which is the number of  elements of vertices, but not the full size of the underlying data... ?
And I was trying different things (like associating the vectors pointer to a target vectors_content)

Do things change in any way if the type Vector also contains other fields, eg with C char ?

@ParkerLewis, the c_f_pointer() call I present in this answer assumes that VerticesVect%size gives the number of Vectors in VerticesVect%data, which I think you have confirmed is correct.  The specifics of the members of Vector should not matter directly; only that they map correctly to the C structure definition.  Every member of the C structure must be mapped, in the same order, with the correct interoperable type.

I'm looking a little deeper right now, but it would help if the question presented a [mre].  In particular, if it disclosed the means by which you are getting those objects into Fortran from C in the first place.

@ParkerLewis, I have added a complete example demonstrating the approach with the C data types you presented.  It works for me.  I'm inclined to suspect that whatever problems you're still having are related to something that you did not disclose in the question. If you agree, then consider posting a new SO question about that.  I think the present one has been thoroughly answered.

@ParkerLewis, I did notice one more thing: the Fortran integer kind corresponding to C type int is c_int, not c_int32_t as you show in your example code, and as I initially replicated in this answer.  The latter corresponds to C type int32_t.  This is sometimes a distinction without a difference, but other times not, depending on your C implementation.  You should match the Fortran kind to the declared type of the thing you are mapping.

Fortran derived types with allocatable or pointer components are not interoperable with C. But you don't need such components here. As confirmed by @Francescalus you should bind the struct Vector* component to a type(c_ptr) component.
And no, you must not get rid of bind(C) !
